# How to know if a coordinate is in or out a polygon ? PHP + google map + JS

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, gps

I've drawn a polygon using google map and i can't find any solution to know if a specific coordinate GPS is in the polygon or out. 
What i need actually is to have the list of coordinate gps in the polygon.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solution based on the google-maps api, you can use the [`google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation` function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#poly).

```
var triangleCoords = [
    {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.19},
    {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
    {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757}
];

var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({paths: triangleCoords});
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(20, -60)
console.log(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, bermudaTriangle));
```

If you are looking for a PHP-based solution - add the geo-library you use in your code.